# C++ timer interrupt for multithreaded program

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, interrupt

I am developing in a Linux environment. Let's assume that I have 3 threads, t1,t2, and t3 running in my software (implemented using pthread). The execution time of thread t1 and t2 without interleaving are ranged from 50ms to 100ms. Is there anyway I can implement thread t3 such that it will issue an interrupt every 30ms (ie. after t3 finished execution[sched_yeild()], the next run will be 30ms later from that point onward and when the 30ms timeout, it will yield whatever thread it is running and run thread t3 until it finished[sched_yeild()])? Below is the structure of my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
    //others header files
void* thread1(void *){
   while(1){
    //code for thread1 :loop time about 50ms-100ms
    sched_yield();
   }
}
void* thread2(void *){
   while(1){
    //code for thread2:loop time about 50ms-100ms
    sched_yield();
   }
}
void* thread3(void *){
   while(1){
    //code for thread3
    sched_yield();
   }
}
int main(){
    pthread_t t1,t2,t3;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,thread2,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t3,NULL,thread3,NULL);

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    pthread_join(t3,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want T3 to (as close as possible to) immediately preempt T1 and T2 and run until it surrenders? Sounds like you want to give T3 a higher priority. But don't count on this for synchronization.

Comment: Define what you mean by "interrupt". The term has many different meanings in this context. Furthermore, you do understand that `sched_yield()` offer no kind of guarantees, whatsoever, what will actually happens. This sounds like an XY problem. Your real problem is something else and you think the solution is what this question describes. Maybe if you describe the real problem, someone can come up with a real solution for you.

Comment: @user4581301 yes. The priority shouldn't work in this case as the current running thread (t1 and t2) are still executing and not giving up the resources.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry for not being clear. In this context, the interrupt that I mean is, whenever the 30ms timer timeout, it will issue a signal such that any running thread will give up CPU resources (preempt) and let T3 to run immediately (T3 is sort of like a interrupt service routine). My actual issue is I am capturing image from thread T3 and I want to have a fix frame rate. Therefore I need T3 to run in a periodic manner.

Comment: Something like this is more akin to a realtime OS, and not generic Linux. There are realtime extensions to the Linux kernel, depending upon one's distribution that may or may not be available. But again: this is an XY problem. Whatever the real problem is, it's far more likely that trying to solve the real problem, instead of the XY problem, will be more productive. Suffice to say there is nothing in the stock Linux OS that can be used to guarantee anything of this sort, whatsoever.

Comment: @user9870, You've lost me. Comments 3 and 4 seem to be saying the exact opposite things.

Comment: 'The priority shouldn't work in this case as the current running thread (t1 and t2) are still executing and not giving up the resources.' what resources?  CPU is not an issue: if T3 has a higher scheduling priority than T1 or T2, then T1 or T2 will be immediately preempted if T3 becomes ready and so T3 will be dispatched 'immediately'.

Answer (score 1):

You can have T3 run at a high priority (via e.g. sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_RR, ...) and you can have T3 run in a loop that calls usleep() to sleep for a certain amount of time, and then when usleep() returns, T3 can do something useful before calling usleep() again.  If you want to get clever, you can even have T3 vary the value it passes to usleep() to make up for the time T3 spent (doing something useful) between usleep() calls to correct for drift, so that (something useful) happens closer to once every 30mS (on average).

However, if you're hoping that T3's behavior will somehow control how/when T1 and T2 execute, you're going to be disappointed.  Threads by their nature execute asynchronously (and unpredictably) with respect to each other by default, and just because T3 is running at a given instant doesn't mean T1 and T2 are not also running at that same instant (think multicore/multiprocessor).

If you're trying to synchronize the execution of threads, then you need to use a proper thread synchronization mechanism, such as a mutex or condition variable.  There really is no substitute.  :)